# Is there a way to run something similar geocoder. So you can inquire more than 2500 per day

Tags: php, geocoding

This code seems to work perfectly, but I cant go over 2500 requests per day.  I have 10s of thousands of records.
Connection

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "searchdb";
$passwd = "mypass";
$dbname = "mydb";
$test_table = "update_lon_lat";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $passwd);             passwd);`enter code here`
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

    $i = 0;
    $empty = "";
```

Select all records where longitude and lat are null

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT client_id, address, city, state, zip FROM $test_table WHERE lat = :lat ");
$stmt->bindValue(':lat' , "$empty", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

If true then calculate new cordinates and write them to table

```
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $i = $i + 1;
        $mapaddress = "";
        $client_id = $row['client_id'];
        $mapaddress =  ($row['address'] . ' ' . $row['city'] . ' ' .  $row['state'] . ' ' . $row['zip']);
```

Start of questionable code below

```
        $address_holder = $mapaddress; // Google HQ
        $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address_holder);
        $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
        $output= json_decode($geocode);
        $lat_holder = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        $longitude_holder = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

End of questionable code above

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE $test_table SET longitude = :longitude, lat = :lat WHERE client_id = :client_id");
$stmt2->bindValue(':longitude' , "$longitude_holder", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindValue(':lat' , "$lat_holder", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindValue(':client_id' , "$client_id", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->execute();

  echo $i . ' ' . $row['address'] . ' ' . $row['city'] . ', ' .            $row['state'] . ' ' . $row['zip'] . ' lon=' . $longitude_holder
. ' Lat=' . $lat_holder . '<br>'; 

}

echo "Records Updated = " . $i;

?>code here
```

Comment: Would it be to expensive to pay for the service? "_Enable pay-as-you-go billing to unlock higher quotas: $0.50 USD / 1000 additional requests, up to 100,000 daily._" Ie, is this a personal project or a business solution?

Comment: This will be for a new Business with one employee.  Me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1
You can unlock higher quotas by spending some money.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits#premium-usage-limits

Option 2
Usage limits are applicable per project.So, create multiple projects and when you hit the maximum allowed limit, just change the client_id to be of some other project which hasn't crossed the maximum quota.

Comment: Maybe I should just spend $399.00 for a pre-built database.  Looks like it would be the cheapest route as I have 49 million records to process.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable cost for that much data to process.

Comment: Was this a good question? anybody.  Want to make sure I format both my question and my examples in a way Stackoverflow likes.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the database for $399.00 only has 28 million records. but they have the long and lat.  I purchase a database with 49 million for $250.00, but no long and lat.  If I did the math correctly, $2500.00 is the cost to process the 49 million with my script above and get it over with.  Any other thoughts?